# Any way to prevent the dome light from being always on

Tags: honda, fit

My Honda Fit 2013 has 3 settings for the interior dome light: off, on temporarily (when opening the door or switching off the ignition) or always on.

This morning I got into the car and found the battery drained because my toddler son switched the light to always on.

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to hack the switch so that it can be either off or temporarily on, but not permanently on.

Comment: Not that I've looked at a Honda Fit switch as such, but would bet you could pull the switch itself apart and block that from working. Maybe you could put something in the way so that the switch will not move over to the always on position. I'm talking on the inside of the switch panel so it's not visible from the outside. Just a thought.

Answer (score 4):

If you remove the switch, there should be three wires going to it - permanent live, switched live, and the one going out to the lamp itself. Disconnect the permanent live, making sure that a) it's not powering anything else, like alarm receivers, and b) that you insulate it properly so it can't touch anything and short out.

Refit the switch and you should be good to go...

Alternatively don't let the toddler play with it ;)

Comment: I like the alternative :)

Answer (score 1):

I like Nick C's idea. An even lower tech approach would be to remove the dome light's bulb.